# Calling methods on sql.NullFloat64 passed in through interface{} throws error

Tags: go

I have a simple function that looks like this:

```
func convertToRealNum(number interface{}) interface{}{
  switch v := number.(type) { 
  default:
    log.Fatal("unexpected type %T", v)
  case sql.NullFloat64:
    newNumber := number.Float64
  case sql.NullInt64:
    newNumber := number.Int64
  }
  return newNumber 
}
```

number is either a `NullFloat64` or a `NullInt64`. If number is the type NullFloat64, I call number.Float64 on it and get back the value of the number as a Float64. If I try to call the same thing inside a function that takes number as an argument that is an interface{} I get the compile error:

`number.Float64 undefined (type interface {} has no field or method Float64)`

Inside the function, if I call reflect.TypeOf(number) it'll return NullFloat64, so it knows what type it is, but I can't call that types methods.

Comment: You need to use `v`, not `number` to access the field values inside the type switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual value of number (whatever type it is) is assigned to `v` in the type switch. The problem is you're re-using `number` in the assignment to `newNumber`, that is still the same old `interface{}` when you go into the `case sql.NullFloat64` that is the type of `v` which has the value of `number` in it so you'll want to use it for assignment.

```
func convertToRealNum(number interface{}) interface{}{
 var newNumber interface{} 
 switch v := number.(type) { 
  default:
    log.Fatal("unexpected type %T", v)
  case sql.NullFloat64:
    newNumber = v.Float64
  case sql.NullInt64:
    newNumber = v.Int64
  }
  return newNumber  
}
```

Comment: That just returns `undefined: Float64` I didn't down vote BTW.

Comment: This is incorrect syntax as well. [This](https://play.golang.org/p/9bysKpaGAe) will work but is a bad idea (e.g. when `Valid` is false).

Comment: @Arel yeah, sorry that should have been `float64` (since it's the type) but my diagnosis of your problem was just incorrect. I skimmed the code a little fast and thought you were trying to a type assert, you're actually just trying to access a property on a type. I'll update my answer when I have a minute.

Comment: @DaveC yeah I didn't really read the code very closely and just thought those were type asserts with syntactical errors. Anyway, I've edited with the correct solution and explanation for what it is that way.

Comment: @Arel apologies on the previous answer, didn't really read your question so much as put down my first thought as an answer. Updated answer should shore things up and will hopefully offer some understanding.